# How to write a jquery ajax REST api function to create a list in SP2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

I am trying to create a list in SP2013 REST. This is what I get

```
        var url = "http://mysite/_api/web/lists";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST", 
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            body: { 
                '__metadata': { 
                    'type': 'SP.List' 
                }, 
                'AllowContentTypes': true, 
                'BaseTemplate': 100,
                'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 
                'Description': 'My list description', 
                'Title': 'Test123' 
            },
            cache: false,
            headers: {
                "Authorization" : "Bearer123",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-length" : 800
            },
            beforeSend : function(jqXHR, settings) {

            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (jqxr, errorCode, errorThrown) {
                alert("Failed");
            }
        });
```

But it doesn't seem to work. The MSDN page is not that helpful since it doesn't give a jquery example, and I can't find any good examples anywhere.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552.aspx

Does anyone know to do it?

with the above, it seems to be returning

```
"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"A node of type 'EndOfInput' was read from the JSON reader when trying to read the start of an entry. A 'StartObject' node was expected.\"}}}"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things are missing, `JSON.stringify` in request payload and send payload in `data` property of `$.ajax`. I am using following

```
var url = "/_api/web/lists";

var data = {
    '__metadata': {
        'type': 'SP.List'
    },
    'AllowContentTypes': true,
    'BaseTemplate': 100,
    'ContentTypesEnabled': true,
    'Description': 'My list description',
    'Title': 'Test123'
};

$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```